# Populating ComboBox Issues

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I am trying to work on my visual basic homework, and I am attempting to assign information to the listbox and it says that the ampersand (&) doesn't belong. If anyone could take a look at my code and tell me how to fix it that would be amazing, I would rather not wait for my prof to wake up to get an answer, thank you in advance.

```vb
Private Sub btnCars_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCars.Click
    'Convert String to Listbox
    txtMake.ToString()
    txtModel.ToString()
    cbxColorCar.ToString()

    'Assign car information to the listbox
    resultsCars = txtMake.Text & " " & txtModel.Text & " " & cbxColorCar & "."
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `cbxColorCar.SelectedItem.ToString()`

Comment: So I just tried that and it's still giving me the same error @braX

Comment: What does your textbook say about how to get the selected value in your case? It needs to be a string variable, so you need to use a property of the combo box, not the combo box itself.

Comment: Those first three lines of code make no sense at all. Stop trying to convert controls to text. All those lines do is create `Strings` containing the names of the controls, e.g. "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox", and then immediately discard them. You don't convert controls to data, you get data out of controls via appropriate members, e.g. `TextBox.Text`, `ComboBox.SelectedValue`, etc, etc.

Comment: jmcilhinney is right. assign the first three lines (ex : dim make = txtMake.Text). For the error, resultsCars is not a string. considere braX's comment

Comment: What is resultCars?

Answer (score 0):

The question, as asked, has got nothing to do with `ListBoxes`. The issue is that you are trying to concatenate a `ComboBox` with a `String`, which makes no sense. See how you used the `Text` property to get the required data out of your `TextBox` controls? Do you suppose that you might need to do something similar to get the required data out of the `ComboBox`? Which property to use depends on how you populated it. If you just added `Strings` to the `Items` collection then you can just use the `Text`, as for the `TextBox`.

You may still have an issue after doing that, depending on what `resultCars` is. If that is the `ListBox` itself then you're stuffed. How does it make sense to assign a `String` to a `ListBox` variable? It doesn't. If you want to add that `String` to the `ListBox` then that's what you actually have to do, which would involve some actual adding.